# Show that $\overline{(\textbf{y},\textbf{x})}_A = (\textbf{x},\textbf{y})_A$

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-verification

I want to show that $\overline{(\textbf{y},\textbf{x})}_A = (\textbf{x},\textbf{y})_A$ where $(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})_A =\textbf{x}^T A \textbf{y}$, $\textbf{x},\textbf{y} \in \mathbb R^p$ and $A$ is a real symmetric $p \times p$ matrix . Here is my approach
$$
\overline{(\textbf{y},\textbf{x})}_A = \overline{\textbf{y}^T A \textbf{x}} = \overline{\textbf{x}^T} \overline{A} \overline{\textbf{y}}
$$
Since $\textbf{x},\textbf{y},$ and $A$ are all real the complex conjugate can be dropped. This yields
$$
\overline{\textbf{x}^T} \overline{A} \overline{\textbf{y}} = \textbf{x}^T A \textbf{y} = (\textbf{x},\textbf{y})_A
$$
Hence
$$
\overline{(\textbf{y},\textbf{x})}_A  = (\textbf{x},\textbf{y})_A
$$

I am not sure about this though
$$
\overline{\textbf{y}^T A \textbf{x}} = \overline{\textbf{x}^T} \overline{A} \overline{\textbf{y}}
$$
I recall reading this property before but I can't figure out what it is now. Is the above equality true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use the identity $(AB)^T$=$B^TA^T$ twice to get the following. (see third identity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose ) 
$$
\overline{(\textbf{y},\textbf{x})}_A = \overline{\textbf{y}^T A \textbf{x}} = {\textbf{x}^T} {A}^T {\textbf{y}}
.$$ Therefore $$
\overline{(\textbf{y},\textbf{x})}_A = {(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})}_{A{^T}}
.$$ So you identity hold if $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: It is symmetric, I forgot to put that in the problem description. So is this the complex conjugate or the conjugate transpose?

Comment: Normally we don't use $^T$ for conjugate transpose. Instead we use $^*$. But the identity still holds even in complex case.

Answer (score 1):

The above is not true. Just take some vectors $x \ne y$ and a non-symmetric matrix $A$. For example,

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}, \quad x = e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad y = e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then

$$\overline{(y,x)}_A = 3, \quad (x,y)_A = 2.$$